# Windows 8 "Close button" not exactly at top right corner of the screen

Tags: windows-8.1

In windows 8.1 , the "Close button" is a a few pixels to the left of the top right corner, so effectively when the mouse is at this location, single click won't close the window (maximized). (it is different from Windows 7).

I also notice that if I double click top right corner, it will close the window.
How to set it to single click to close ?

[image]

Edit : Here is a video if you guys don't believe me , the mouse came from bottom left went straight to top right, as it crossed the X button, **the X button lit up**, then as the mouse went passed the X button into the few pixels at very right border the X button **then it went out**

[image]

(note: there shouldn't be any space on the border, it just the capture program it adds to)

Comment: "it is different from Windows 7"  you are right, the default visible gap there was LARGER in previous versions of Windows. But what's your question to us?  Also, double-clicking the LEFT upper corner to close a Window is a long-standing Windows feature left over from when every Window had an icon there to click -- is this what you want to change to single-click?  What have you tried/found already when you researched it?

Comment: The clickzone extends all the way to the edge of the screen. You sure you’re clicking right? ;)

Comment: I am sorry, I just switched to Windows 8.1 and I noticed this immediately. In windows 7, when the mouse is right at top right corner of the screen, the "X button" is selected and single click will close it. In windows 8, when the mouse is at top right corner of the screen, "X button" is selected but, single click won't close it. Double click will do, but then again, I always thought buttons are supposed to be clicked (single)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small .ahk script. Hit Windows R, type 'shell:startup', download AHK and create a .ahk file with the below text in your startup folder to make it run on login. Make sure to get the right xPos for your monitor - for reference, mine is 1920 pixels width. All the script does is detect left clicks and sends through another click if you are in that top right corner, removing the need to double click.

It seems like a bug in Windows 8 - I've had it happen to me from time to time.

```
#InstallMouseHook
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
loop {
    KeyWait, LButton, D
    MouseGetPos, xPos, yPos
    if(xPos==1919 and yPos==0){
        MouseClick, Left
    }
}

!F1::
ExitApp
```